# apache2 how to rewrite to special scheme

Tags: url-rewriting, apache2

I wonder if there's easy way to let apache2 support URL rewrite to special schemes like "macappstore", "itms" and so on.

```
RewriteRule ^/pbmac-test$  macappstore://itunes.apple.com/us/app/id420133782  [R,L]
```

http://TLD/pbmac-test will be rewrote as http://TLD/macappstore://itunes.apple.com/us/app/id420133782

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mod_rewrite` is not detecting `macappstore` as a valid protocol for an absolute URI. See `is_absolute_uri` in [mod_rewrite.c](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/httpd/httpd/tags/2.2.17/modules/mappers/mod_rewrite.c?view=markup) for more details.

This leads it to treat your target URI as relative rather than absolute. The `R` flag will prepend the current protocol, server name and port to the relative URIs in order to produce RFC correct redirect headers [as documented](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_r).

For redirects as simple as the one you presented, you can use [mod_alias](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect) instead:

```
Redirect /pbmac-test macappstore://itunes.apple.com/us/app/id420133782
```